# Quiz module - Results comments: Using points score instead of percentage

Tags: quiz

I am using quiz module and I have this:

Question 1:

a) Gathers 0 points

b) Gathers 0,25 points

c) Gathers 0,5 points

d) Gathers 1 point

I want the quiz to sum those points and show a final result if points are between [0-30] [31-60] [61-90] [91-120] [121-150]

I found this option:

[image]

But this only shows percentage... I wanted something like "Points Start Range" and "Points End Range"

Do you guys understand my issue here?

Thank you!!

Comment: I found this module that does exactly what I want... https://www.drupal.org/project/personality_test

But this way I can't store all the responses/results, and that's very important for me so I guess it's not a good solution

Comment: I just need to change Percentage to points. Can I do this in the code?

Comment: Can you post some more info and print screens on what quiz sub modules you have enabled and what screen you are on when you are accessing those percentages? The quiz module is dense. You'll need to do a hook_form_alter, a submit handler, and a display handler. With more info, we might be able to help you with this.